# type Command Shows 3 Identical Locations for File

Tags: linux, bash, msysgit, git-bash, tee

In msysGit, when I run `type -a tee(.exe)`, it shows me 3 lines with the same file:

```
$ type -a tee.exe
tee.exe is /bin/tee.exe
tee.exe is /bin/tee.exe
tee.exe is /bin/tee.exe
tee.exe is /c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/tee.exe
tee.exe is /c/Program Files (x86)/Drush/GnuWin32/bin/tee.exe
```

However, this is not the case when I input the same line in a Fedora 20 VM running on the same machine:

```
[sean@localhost ~]$ type -a tee
tee is /bin/tee
tee is /usr/bin/tee
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: What's your $PATH set to in each case?

Comment: You got me. I had several folders repeated 3 times. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my PATH has some folders repeated several times. Thanks to @rojomoke for pointing out the possibility.

My msysGit PATH is

```
$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/Sean/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Users/Sean/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/min
n:/c/Users/Sean/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd:/c/Pro
 (x86)/Git/bin:/c/MinGW/bin:/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin:/c/Python33/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Inte
ent/:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System3
WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
s/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x
Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management
mponents/IPT:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin/:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/Wireless
/strawberry/c/bin:/c/strawberry/perl/site/bin:/c/strawberry/perl/bin:/c/Program Files/Micr
Platform Installer/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0/:/c/Pr
s (x86)/Windows Kits/8.0/Windows Performance Toolkit/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Serve
s/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/90/Tools/binn/:/c/Program Files/nodejs
am Files (x86)/OpenAFS/Common:/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/c/HashiCorp/Vagr
/Ruby200-x64/bin:/c/Users/Sean/AppData/Local/Box/Box Edit/:/c/Program Files (x86)/SSH Comm
 Security/SSH Secure Shell:/c/ProgramData/Drush/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Drush/GnuWin32/bin
m Files (x86)/Drush/Php:/c/Users/Sean/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/Sean/Documents/Lisp:/c/
les/GCL-2.6.1/lib/gcl-2.6.1/unixport:/c/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/bin:/c/Program Files/Or
alBox:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin:/c/Program Files/eclipse
```

This was because I was experimenting with logging into `Git Bash`. I found out the shortcut to call `Git Bash`:

```
`/bin/sh --login -i`
```

and was experimenting. This line calls all the scripts that are called when `Git Bash` starts but, as you can probably imagine, it calls them *on top of* scripts that were already called, and so any files added to the PATH are added *again*.

Comment: You probably source a script somewhere that contains the line `PATH=/c/Users/Sean/bin:$PATH`, so that your directory gets added every time it is run.